# does icecast force ssl if enabled?

Tags: ssl, https, icecast, internet-radio

In the documentation for icecast 2.4.2 I see the following about ssl.

> ssl If set to 1 will enable HTTPS on this listen-socket. Icecast must
>   have been compiled against openSSL to be able to do so.

However this wording is unclear to me whether or not the ssl is forced for this port or not? I am wondering this because we are running into an issue where safari is forcing ssl redirect and we want to keep the server listening on both ssl and non-ssl on the same port ( if thats possible )

Another thing is that it says it must be compiled against openSSL but we are installing it from `apt` in `xenial`. Does this mean its default to ssl?

Thanks~!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "forced".

Comment: Will all traffic be redirected to ssl?

Comment: Please note that the default Ubuntu packages (as they descend from Debian) are built **without openSSL**.  How to get a version that is compiled against openSSL on Debian or Ubuntu? [Use the official Xiph.org Icecast packages.](https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_(official_Xiph_repositories))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However this wording is unclear to me whether or not the ssl is forced for this port or not?

On that particular socket, it is.  A server bound to that socket cannot support HTTPS and non-HTTPS at the same time.  Usually, you'll use port `80` for HTTP and port `443` for HTTPS.

Note that you can have multiple sockets bound to Icecast, simply by putting in multiple `<listen-socket>` sections.  It's common to serve both HTTP and HTTPS this way.

> I am wondering this because we are running into an issue where safari is forcing ssl redirect

Your server configuration is irrelevant here.  Icecast will not redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.  It's possible that you hit the stream on HTTPS once and that Safari cached this.  It's also possible that you turned on HSTS or something for your domain.  You would have to debug this with a tool like Fiddler.

> and we want to keep the server listening on both ssl and non-ssl on the same port

You say "keep the server listening"... that's not possible.  If it appears you're set up this way today, that's not accurate.

Answer (score -2):

In a sense it does. Icecast if you are using it as its own server will not resolve the enabled ssl port unless its `https://`.

You also cannot use the same port for both ssl and non-ssl.

Finally the xenial ubuntu package also is *not* compiled for ssl.